# How to close particular bootstrap modal popup when multiple modal popups opened?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap Modals in my application.

In one of my requirement, on one modal dialog box another modal dialog box will open.
For the both modal dialogs I set data-backdrop and data-keyboard.

When I click on close button on second modal dialog both the modal dialogs are closing.

To restrict that I wrote one function to hide that specific modal dialog.

Now my question is I can see data-backdrop for the total page after closing the first modal dialog.

I used below to overcome that but no luck.

Script function I used is:

```
function preventCloseModal(ele) {
    $(ele).modal('hide');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove()
}
```

HTML of that Close Button is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="preventCloseModal('#distributorDetailsPanel');">Close</button>
```

Please advice to overcome from this.

Comment: You say "Now my question is"...but then the text which follows is not a question. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Hi ADyson, After using the mentioned JavaScript code i can close the single modal but the backdrop of that modal still remains the same after closing the all modal popups.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can find closest model from your button elements like this way.

```
function preventCloseModal(ele) {
            $(ele).closest(".modal").modal('hide');
            $(ele).closest('.modal-backdrop').remove()
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code snippet which you provided is working but that is disabling the backdrop of all the modals. I want to remove the backdrop of that particular modal only.

Answer (score 0):

Take reference from below code for proper format of modal pop-up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .modal-header, h4, .close {
      background-color: #5cb85c;
      color:white !important;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
  }
  .modal-footer {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Login Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="myBtn">Login</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usrname" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="psw"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Password</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="psw" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
            </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
          <p>Not a member? <a href="#">Sign Up</a></p>
          <p>Forgot <a href="#">Password?</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If still not resolved, share whole code snippet for proper resolution.

Comment: Hi Manveer Singh, I can able to popup the modal, But in my requirement i have 3 modals which are population according to requirement. So when close the latest modal the other 2 modals still need to exist. But using the mentioned JavaScript code(Which i mentioned in question) I'm able to close the particular modal but failed to remove the backdrop of the modal.

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap modal: close current, open new
A proper and clean way to get this done without additional Javascript/jQuery.**

Launch Modal #1
      Launch Modal #2
      Launch Modal #3

```
  <!-- [ Modal #1 ] -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="demo-1" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-xs-o-md"></i></button>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title caps"><strong>Demo Modal #1</strong></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Placeholder..." />
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Action</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-2" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-3" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #3</button>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- [ Modal #2 ] -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="demo-2" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-xs-o-md"></i></button>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title caps"><strong>Demo Modal #2</strong></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Placeholder..." />
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Action</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-1" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-3" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #3</button>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- [ Modal #3 ] -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="demo-3" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-xs-o-md"></i></button>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title caps"><strong>Demo Modal #3</strong></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Placeholder..." />
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Action</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-1" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-2" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #2</button>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```